# Update forked project on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Let's say a repository from which I clone (and only read-only for me) is:

```
git@github.com:secret_project/dev.git  branch: dev
```

I forked project and URL:

```
git@github.com:secret_user/Dde.git
```

(Which I have full access to: read+write)

But someone updated `git@github.com:secret_project/dev.git` from another forked version.

Let's say file changed on

```
git@github.com:secret_project/dev.git  (test.txt)
content:
hi!
```

But my forked project has `test.txt` file with content:

```
hi
```

So how do I update the forked project locally and in my repository?

Which commands should I use? And please make an example with my showed repositories...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository)

Comment: @kapa : `How to update GitHub forked repository?` is newer than this post ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should add the remote address for the original repository '`upstream`' to your local repository (which is a clone of your `Dde.git` fork):

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/secret_project/dev.git # public read-only URL
```

That will allow you to pull '`upstream`' into your own branch (merging and resolving any merge conflict in `test.txt`).
Then you will push your local branch to your `Dde` GitHub repository.

See [GitHub help page: "Working with remotes"](http://help.github.com/remotes/) for more details.

Comment: If you name it `upstream` — so, type `git remote add upstream` instead of `git remote add dev` — you'll be able to follow [GitHub's documentation "Syncing a fork"](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/). You'll also stay clearer on which development is yours and which was done, well, upstream.

Comment: @fureigh Thank you. I usually do that in later answers (like http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309), but I apparently did not have that practice 5+ years ago. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! (Also, I notice in retrospect that my tone could've read as snarky — it certainly wasn't intended that way, so if it came off that way, my apologies.)

Answer (score 1):

Just send out a pull request from your repository's GitHub page to your Parent repository. Then pull the changes in your local forked repo and commit and send a fresh pull request.