# Forking a repository that got updated in GitHub

Tags: git, github, fork

What is the best way to get an updated repository? There is usually a button that says "Fork" but a "Your Fork" button takes its place. Is this because I have already forked an older version of the repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the original repository as a source to your local git repository

```
cd /my/local/repository
git remote add upstream git@github.com/author/originalrepo.git
```

You can chose whatever name you want, but I usually stick with upstream.

With `git pull upstream master` you can grab the master branch from the original repo, merge in the changes and with `git push origin master` push it up to your fork

Answer (score 2):

You can update your repository via command

```
git fetch
```

Then look around and do merge/rebase if necessary.