# Permission denied (publickey) on github when fetching from upstream

Tags: github, ssh-keys

i can't seem to fetch changes from upstream with ssh key authentication.

I can add the repo just fine:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Contents of my ssh folder seem ok:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Logging in works perfectly:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi user/repo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But fetch from upstream doesn't work:

```
$ git fetch upstream
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

If you do not "own" the remote you should just use the read-only link

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/antirez/redis
```

Comment: Very use full description and command. It's saved my lot of time. Very thanks for your informative answer.