# How to take update from github repository?

Tags: github

I have installed `GitHub Client` to my system.

I have easy to commit my changes to the repository. But my colleague tried to take my update, he is not able to took the app from repository.

We are having GitHub private repository.

Kindly let me know to solve this issue.

Comment: Have You checked http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics ?

Answer (score 0):

The similar question has been asked before follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository) hope it may help you.

Basic flow is like this.

```
# clone the repository (from github, for example)
git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git
cd reponame    

# edit some files

# add them to the index
git add file1.txt
git add file2.gif

# review your changes
git status    

# commit the changes
git commit -m "Decription of my change"

# push them back to the remote repository
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

If your colleague is supposed to:

- access your private repo
- be able to contribute back (git push) directly to that private repo

you should add him/her to the list of collaborators for this project: see "[GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator)".

Note that Users can always collaborate on private repositories, even on the free plan.
I.e. if a user has a GitHub account (even a free one), he/she can be added to a *private* repository.