# Set content to aloha editable?

Tags: javascript, html, aloha-editor

I am setting a content to aloha editable but i am getting an error message saying that "Aloha.activeEditable is null". Can anybody please tell me how to solve this ??

```
Aloha.activeEditable.setContents('', true);
```

Error : Type error : Aloha.activeEditable is null

Answer (score 1):

Source : https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/pull/642

> The problem is that there is no active editable when the attributes
>   are changed the first time (Aloha.activeEditable is null).
>
> There was an API change. Was fixed by user [deliminator](https://github.com/deliminator) in [bf4033b](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/commit/bf4033b749a8ab91006390bfe0d407b1d1243bf4). Please update
>   your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response..how and where do i update my code??

Comment: About the 'how' that will be another question "How to update aloha editable coding". About the 'where' : https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor

Comment: I won't be of much help about updating from a github repository, it's something documented on github site YOU will have to read, but you can find this answer helpfull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264119/how-to-take-update-from-github-repository