# Updating forked GitHub repo to match original's latest code and commits

Tags: github, fork, git-pull

I forked a GitHub project several days ago and from its issues, I can see that the master branch has had some modifications since.

When I `cd` to my location directory of this project and use `git pull`, it says, "Already up-to-date". Why?

How do I update my fork to include the commits from the original repo?

Comment: Blatant duplicate of super-popular question [How to update GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you fork a repository, a *copy* of the original repository is established on your GitHub account. This permits read+write access to the "copy".

When the original repository resource has commits that would benefit your copy, follow these steps to update your fork's master branch. You could update other branches, but typical workflow is to update `master` against the original repository.

1. Open a Terminal
2. `cd` to your project directory
3. `git remote add upstream <url-of-original-repository>`
4. `git branch` and verify you are on `master` branch
5. `git pull --rebase upstream master`

Step #5 will fetch all new commits of the "original" repository, apply them to `master` branch from the last `merge-base`, then include all of your branch's commits "on top".

Any time you need to update your fork again, simply run the command in step #5.

Comment: Another question please ,after I modified some code ,and according to github tutorial ,  I use "git push origin master" to push the modification to my forked project.after that ,I pull request , github says: "There isn't anything to compare.

nferraz:master is up to date with all commits from VicoWu:master. Try switching the base for your comparison." It seems that my push takes no effect.Why  this happened?

Comment: Push pushes your local commits to your remote repository (ie. github). If those are the only commits to the remote repository since your last pull, there's nothing to pull because you already have the commits. :)