# How to keep updating from master repo using git?

Tags: git, github

I don't quite understand the concept of using git

Let's say I clone a repo from Laravel/Laravel using

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git lrv4
```

I then work on my own, then a while after that, Laravel push some updates to the repo, I don't understand what I have to do to keep my own project up to date with Laravel's core???

Forking? Merging? Pulling? or what?

Thanks.

I'm using ubuntu 13.4.

Comment: I think that first you need to read a little about git, this tutorial is quite good http://try.github.io and github help https://help.github.com/. Is fork not flok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull
```

gets the changes from the remote into your local repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to first "get" the latest code from repo using:

```
git fetch
```

Then, merge your own changes to the fetched code:

```
git merge
```

But git has a command which does both these things, in that order, for you:

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms, you'll merge the changes from the remote repository into your local branch.

If you are working on the 'master' branch of lrv4 you can use 'git pull' to fetch and merge the changes on the remote repository. If you have local changes, you will need to commit those before you pull.

Eventually head over to http://gitref.org/ and read more. Git can really grow on you but it takes a little getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track it by

```
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

Then merge the latest code to your own branch by

```
$ git pull upstream master
```

---

B.t.w., you can track any other repos (there're other users like you forked the original user's repo and do their own modification) in this way. Just name a name for them like `upstream`. Generally speaking, `upstream` is always for original repo.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows).

An alternative to pulling is

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Fetch gets the new commits in the repo and stores them in your .git folder. You can see them with `git log`. Rebase attempts to do something like a merge, but without creating a separate merge commit. If merge conflicts happen, you will need to resolve them in this tep. You can always roll back if the merge goes wrong: `git rebase --abort`.