# Github, how do I sync my branch to the master?

Tags: linux, git, github

I've just recently started working with git and github.

I forked a project, contributed to it and created a pull request. That pull request was merged.

In the mean time, the project I forked has had new changes pulled into it.  Now I want to grab those changes so that my forked project is identical to the project head.

How do I do it?  Following this link [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)  Didn't work.

```
$ git fetch upstream
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: More of a super user question.

Comment: Not when you consider there 11k questions using the github tag and 48k using the git tag.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/1928529). You probably didn't add the `upstream` remote

Comment: Think I might be confusing the terminology, it's a fork not a branch.  Git is rather different to subversion.

Comment: Thanks @dennisschagt, that answer worked perfectly.  Not my fork/branch says it's even with the original repository.

Comment: @Matt Glad to be of help. I've added it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add a remote called `upstream`. You can add it by executing `git remote add upstream <git-repository-url>`. When you are at the project page on GitHub you can find the git-repository-url on the right, there it is called `clone URL`. After you added the `upstream` remote you can execute the steps you originally found. When updating a fork, a rebase could make the history cleaner. Check [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/1928529) to see how that is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try git pull. Or git pull origin master if you are on the master branch.

Comment: Yeah that was useless... it said it was up to date.  But on github it says it's 5 commits behind even after I did a push.

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/ try doing this :

```
git pull https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: I believe that should work but it I think it's better (more efficient/clear) to add a remote, called something like `upstream`, and then fetch from there.