# GitHub: Creating a repository from an existing one and keeping it up to date with the original

Tags: github

There is an existing Open Source Project, say A, on GitHub which I have cloned. I have some requirements which will need modifying some of the features of this Open Source Project. So, I was thinking of creating a new Git Repository with the latest code of A and commit all my changes to this new repository, say B.

However, if there are any new changes in A, I would like to merge them with my project B. (I don't want to commit my changes to A).

I have never used GitHub (only used SVN). What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can fork latest code from repo A and create your own repo with your credentials then create a new branch. You can commit your code changes to your repo B's new branch.

Comment: you can take help from below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called a [`remote`](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/). After you have forked the project and cloned it locally, you can just add the original as a remote by using:

```
git remote add myremote https://github.com/user/original_repo
```

After that you can pull from that remote by running

```
git pull myremote master
```

You can of course pull also any branch other than `master`. Pushing is similar.

You can also see a list of all remotes by one of the following commands:

```
git remote show
git remote -v
```

The full documentation can be found [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and a great tutorial is [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)