# Using Git to keep source from a project up to date but also retain my modifications

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap

I want to work on a GitHub hosted project (panique/huge) to make it into a bootstrap version.  Panique quite reasonably doesn't want to add any framework, so I would like to modify my copy, but also use any patches that are added into the Git master, without making it unworkable keeping my copy up to date.  I don't imagine I want to fork the project?  I'm new to Git and can't see how this works, any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want to do:

- Fork the project on GitHub into your own account.
- Clone your fork to your local machine.
- Hack away on your changes, ideally in a branch.
- Feel free to push the branch to your fork on GitHub.

That's the typical way to make changes to existing projects.

If you want to contribute some of your changes back to the original project, create a Pull Request - see [here for more info](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

If you want to update your fork with changes from the original repo, you need to update it from the *upstream* repository. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for more info.

Forking a project is nothing unusual, it's a really common thing - don't be afraid.