# how to update forked repository

Tags: github

When a fork is not up to date, it says :

```
This branch is N commit behind xxx:master
```

How can I simply update the fork ?
Why there's no button to simply update the fork ?

Sorry, but I've tried finding an answer since many hours.

Comment: Someone remove me a point. Please explain me why. I just need help.

Comment: I can update by doing another 'pull request', but the author is then advised of the 'pull request'. He doesn't have to be advised, I simply want to update the fork !    What should be done ?

Comment: Here you have the trick.

[How to update forked repository][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. So I guess it's not possible to do that on the github website.

Answer (score 0):

Do yo have an error? I don't get you what is your point buddy.
May be try to override and update your local changes:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: The point is that the fork update doesn't seem possible to be done on the github website (like a pull request).

Comment: got it, you must make a pull request! https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/