# How do I clone a repository from git but still get updates made to the original repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-clone

I'd like to "clone" an open source application on github to configure it and make a modified version of it.

I figured the cloning and changing part tho I can't seem to figure out this. How can I clone the repo, but maintain a "relation" to the original one since it's still under development and many patches are pushed regularly. So how can I get the updates once they are available without saving my changes separately and re merge with every new version?

ps:my terminology is pretty limited when it comes to git, so please do correct me if i did mention anything wrong.

Comment: If I get you right, you are looking for [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/4832389

Comment: Pretty sure you are asking about `rebase`: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: @Joe , the link is very helpful it's closely related to what I am trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I wasn't aware of the rebase concept. thank you for pointing it out, I think that is what I was looking for. i'll give it a try! just to clarify, i want to get the repo and any updates pushed to it after i's been copied, and maintain any changes made locally to it(ones i made after cloning) i hope this clears the picture of what i am trying to ask about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, I found this [link](https://github.com/GarageGames/Torque2D/wiki/Cloning-the-repo-and-working-with-Git) to be really helpful.

Here's a simple walkthrough:

1. Fork the repo you are in need of.
   [Do so by clicking the fork button in the repository page.]
2. make sure to **Watch** and **Star** the repo to get notified when any new updates pop up.[the watch and star button are also found in the repository page as well]
3. clone the forked repo to you local machine, this is now your working directory.
4. Now we want to setup a **remote** that will track the original repo

   ```
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git
   ```

this will add a new remote called 'upstream' which points to the official Torque2D repository.

5. now we need to create a new branch, naming it whatever you want, type in :

   ```
   git branch branch_name
   ```

we switch to the new branch with the checkout command, making 'branch_name' our currently active branch; we target the most recent version of the repository that is linked to our **upstream remote** and pull in the contents of its development branch into our currently active local branch.

for me this worked, the remote link was the missing piece of the puzzle, [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) was an epic feature someone pointed out in the comments section above which made life a bit easier when it comes to merging updates from different branches.