# How to "re-fork" (or re-base?) w/o use of command line

Tags: git, github, version-control

Not sure if this is possible or not, but figured I'd ask.  I've seen solutions to "re-fork" (is the term rebase?) via [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-github-forked-repository), and solutions to do it via the [website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31010), but not in an ideal way.

Is there a way to do it via the website in an "ideal" way?

Here's why I find my current method less than ideal:

Find a project fork I haven't touched in a while, where originating project is ahead in commits:

[image: out of date fork]

Click green "refresh"y looking button, get the following:

[image: refreshy button]

Switch the base:

[image: base switched]

Am now able to create a pull request to my own fork that will "re-fork/re-base" my fork off of the originating project:

[image: pull request creation]

Now I can merge the pull request into my fork:

[image: merging]

So that's all well and good(ish) - the problem I have with this approach, is now my fork is considered 1 commit ahead of the base:

[image: 1 commit ahead]

Which unfortunately means, if i hit the "refresh"y green button again, it will allow me to in essence create a blank pull request to the repo owner, in this case Microsoft.  Additionally, my profile view now shows a merge under contribution activity:

[image: merge]

I'm new to GitHub and Git in general, so maybe I'm just missing it.  I would like to be able to update my fork from base without using the command line, and without the steps above (as per the issues with "1 commit ahead", and unwarranted contribution activity).

Is there a way to do this?  Or do I have to go the command line route as pointed out in the linked answer?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the command line?  It looks like a perfectly fine method to me.

Comment: The '1 commit ahead' is due to the merge commit; you'd have that with the commandline too. Only fast forwards don't have that problem. A `git pull; git push` on the commandline does look simpler, though!

Comment: @Kevin I guess I can use the command line, I would just prefer not to if it's possible.  Asking mostly for curiosities sake - if there's no way to do it I'll do it the command line way.

Comment: just remember that the command line is the full i/f into git and all of the GUIs build on that so I think all of them are proper subsets in terms of feature space.