# How to fetch changes from master repository?

Tags: git, github

I have forked one repo MasterRepo and its showing in my repository. LocalRepo.

When ever I maded changes and push its get updated in my repo that is LocalRepo.

But If someone change anything in MasterRepo than how would I get changes.

I know command is
    git pull
but my confusion is if I use git pull changes will com from my localrepo or from master repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: [How to update a Github fork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` will pull your default remote and branch. But you can also specify the remote and the branch you want to pull from - e.g.:

```
git pull upstream develop
```

If you just cloned your fork you might have to add the master repo remote with

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```