# Clone Git repo so I can keep it updated with original, but keep my changes separate

Tags: git, bitbucket, phpbb, git-clone, git-fork

My apologies in advance for any misuse of git terminology...

I have an existing phpbb site.  I would like to clone their repo, apply my changes, and create my own repo, in a way that way I can apply updates from the original phpbb master branch as they make them, and so I can maintain my own customizations.  I'm just not entirely sure the order in which I should go about doing this.  I'm not even sure if what I want to do is a fork?

**What I want:**

- To be able to update my site from the phpbb master branch at my discretion.
- To have my repo private (using bitbucket).

I know the files in their master branch that I'll need to change to make the site my own.  So here's how I think it should work, though it probably won't because I never get this stuff right without asking for help first:

- Clone phpbb to my local machine
- Apply my current changes
- Make a new repo on BitBucket
- And here's where I'm confused - I know I need to do something with the remote/origin repos, but most guide available should you how to do a standard fork/pull or a clone - though I want my code to be possibly updated by the origin, but I never want to update their original code.

I have a dev, several test, and a prod machine, so I'd like an easier way to keep all this code up to date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 6):

The usual thing to do is to keep two remotes: `origin` (your private fork) and `upstream` (the real one).

1. Create your private fork and clone it (it will be empty)
2. Add the "real one": `git remote add upstream <url-of-the-real-one>`
3. Download upstream commits: `git fetch upstream`
4. Force-apply upstream commits: `git reset --hard upstream/master`
5. Now your local repository is no longer empty. Push the commits to `origin`: `git push`
6. Apply your local edits, `git commit` them, and `git push` them

Now, if the `upstream/master` branch changes, you need to:

1. Download again the updated commits: `git fetch upstream`
2. Merge the `upstream/master` branch onto your local `master` branch: `git merge upstream/master`
3. If step 2 generates conflicts you should [resolve them](http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/command-line/advanced-topics/merge-conflicts)
4. Update your private fork: `git push`