# GitHub Fork Master Repository

Tags: git, github

I a a newbie in Git. I am using GitHub and the Git addin for Eclipse. I have a master Repository from an other user which I have forked(cloned) to my user where I have made a change in a file. I have cloned my repository from GitHub to my eclipse -> made the change and committed  & pushed my change. Now I have in GitHub my change in my repository and I have asked a pull request so that the other user can commit it in his repository. So far no problems. But of course other users have made some changes also and the master-user has committed some of these already and I can see them in his github repository. Now I want to fork another time but I don't get these changes into my GitHub Clone repository and I don't know why. 
Can you explain me the problem please. I also have not found the merge function or something like that

Comment: You don't need to fork again, you need to sync your current fork with the master repository. Have you read the GitHub guidance? https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)