# How to update angular2 seed project?

Tags: angular

I'm using an early version of angular2-seed with angular2-version-RC1. A lot has been changed in RC5 and i want to update my seed project.
I am thinking about these options for updating the seed->
1.Should i be replacing all other folders other than the src folder where i have my code?
2.Should i take a look at all the files that have been changed and try to make those changes to my existing Project? 
is there a better way to do this? Can someone suggest me the easiest way to update.Thank you

Comment: which seed you are using, can you provide a link?

Comment: This one--https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: If your project is not super large, I would suggest you to get new version of seed and transfer your code components one by one to new seed and fix is something goes wrong, because there was a lot of changes between rc1 and rc5.

Comment: Ok @Mikki i will transfer my code one at a time as my project right now is not heavy but when seed project is changed to RC6(assuming ng2 guys will release) then how should i update.Seed project guys don't have any change log file so that i can replace the changed files in seed with the files in my project?

Comment: That is tricky question because as you said they don't have changelog, and NG2 changes strategy not making it easier but as an answer for your question I would say you can try to make your repository as a fork of angular seed, and once they update it to new version you can sync it with forks father. [Here is some info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository) about it

Comment: I did as per https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed#how-to-update and then merged my project with latest changes. I agree that if project is big, it will be more difficult.