# How can I set upstream repo after adding origin repo in cycligent git tool?

Tags: git, github

I'm playing around with a new git gui, https://www.cycligent.com/git-tool

I didn't find any online documentation, and lost myself when I tried to add upstream repo after adding origin repo, which is my fork.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the [remote section help](https://cycligent.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/q-how-do-i-add-a-remote-repo?from_search=true):

> - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click on Push or Pull in the diagram
> - Click "Show Remote Manager"
> - Choose "Or click here to add a remote."
> - Fill out the name and URL
> - Click submit

But the idea behind a second upstream repo is to be able to [rebase one's branch on top of `upstream/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984149/6309)... and [rebase is not yet fully supported](https://cycligent.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/q-how-do-i-rebase?from_search=true).

> Currently we're still working on fleshing out all of the various ways that rebasing can be done.
>   Right now the only way to rebase is via a pul

Comment: There can be other reasons for multiple upstream repositories. It's an easy way to setup redundancy for example.

Comment: @Ilion I agree, but the OP mentioned "fork" in the question, which made me think of this particular use case.

Comment: Thanks. Turned out, it has the forked repo saved in it. Interesting... because I can not see the comparison.