# How to synchronize fork with original GitHub project?

Tags: git, github

I created the fork of some GitHub project. Then I created new branch and did a patch inside of that branch. I sent the *pull request* to author and he applied my patch and added some commits later. How can I synchronize my fork on GitHub with original project now? Am I to delete my fork on GitHub and create new fork for each my patch each time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't need to `refork` again. Just add a remote (say, `upstream`) and `fetch upstream` to update your cloned repository.

```
$ git remote add upstream <original-repo-url>
$ git fetch upstream                 # update local with upstream

$ git diff HEAD..upstream/master     # see diffs between local and upstream/master (if there is no diff then both are in sync)

$ git pull upstream master           # pull upstream's master into local branch
$ git push origin HEAD               # push to your forked repo's remote branch
```

Fetch/get the original repo's new `tags`:

```
$ git fetch upstream --tags    # get original repo's tags
$ git push origin --tags       # push to forked repo
```

Comment: will this sync all new tags from the original project?

Comment: @eastwater to sync the tags: `git fetch upstream --tags; git push origin --tags`

Comment: thanks. how about one tag only?

Comment: if you want to push only one tag then try this: `$ git push origin refs/tags/<tag-name>`