# Github how to update the forked repo, entirely the same as newly forked

Tags: git

Many days ago, I forked the Airflow repo and I modified a little then submitted a PR.

But today, I want to submit another PR, so I need to re-fork the latest Airflow source code, and discard all the changes in my repo.

A clumsy way is to delete my repo, then fork the official repo again. Actually, after searching, it doesn't have to delete and fork.

#### What I tried:

```
$ git remote add upstream <original-repo-url>
$ git fetch upstream                 # update local with upstream

$ git diff HEAD..upstream/master     # see diffs between local and upstream/master (if there is no diff then both are in sync)

$ git pull upstream master           # pull upstream's master into local branch
$ git push origin HEAD               # push to your forked repo's remote branch
```

In this way, however, I have to `git commit` before `git push origin master`, so there is an additional commit showing in my repo.

My question is how can I update the forked repo, just like a newly forked repo.

#### Reference

[How to synchronize fork with original GitHub project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542640/how-to-synchronize-fork-with-original-github-project)
[How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git pull --rebase upstream & git push origin rejects non-fast-forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661059/git-pull-rebase-upstream-git-push-origin-rejects-non-fast-forward)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to `pull` the changes from upstream, `rebase` option will put your changes on top of synced changes from upstream.

`pull` will `fetch` and `merge` the changes automatically however you may have conflicts in some files that were out of sync or outdated.

`$ git pull upstream --r`

update your fork with your changes + synched changes from `upstream`, sometimes you may have situation where there are some changes in your remote fork that are not in your local git. in this case you can `pull` such  changes from your fork and merge locally or use `force` or `-f`  option to force pushing and overwriting your fork.

`$ git push origin branch`

Now you can safely open PR from github itself.

I hope this helps you out, if not please feel free to leave comment and I would be happy to help more and update my answer