# Force rebase a forked repo to align upstream

Tags: git, github

I have a forked repo that I forked a few months ago.

I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository) to update my repo, when I do `git rebase upstream/master`, I get a conflict (but I never touch my master branch before, maybe the upstream repo has used force push?)

After resolved the conflict, another conflict comes.. I don't want to resolve all of them by hands, I just want to replace my master branch to sync with the upstream one, is there anything like *force rebase*?

Comment: `another conflict comes` ... this is how rebasing works.  If you don't want to rebase, you can try merging instead, e.g. `git merge upstream/master`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried `git merge`, and got tons of conflicts. Also wouldn't `git merge` generate a merge commit?

Comment: If you don't want a merge commit, then rebasing is probably your only option.  But there is no avoiding conflicts between the two branches, conflicts which appear in rebase would also appear using merge, though possibly in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I make it works.

After fetch the upstream, just reset to the `upstream/master`

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```