# how to make fork on github updated

Tags: github, git-fork

I found good project (boilerplate), which I am going to use as starting point for my project.
And I forked it.

```
git clone https://github.com/fork.git forkdirectory  # clone my fork to my local PC
git branch mybranch #  create new branch for my specialities, which will be different from boilerplate
git checkout steklo  # change the branch, which I will work on by default
```

Then I make some changes and check that they appear in my fork

```
git add . # add all changes for commit 
git commit -m"commit comments"  # make commit
git push -u origin mybranch # push changes to mybranch
```

I tested that for next changes I can just do shorter

```
git push
```

But what should I do when I will see that initial boilerplate updated?

1) How to apply all updates to my fork?

2) And then how to apply all updates from my fork to my local clone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand your confusion about it,

This process steps are

1. Fork the repository.
2. Update the repository.
3. Create a pull request
4. Now Owner of the repository sees, if your request is valid, he merge the request.

You've already completed first two steps, now you only need to submit a pull request.

**Goto Pull requests of your forked repo**

[image]

**Create a new pull request**

[image]

**Owner will see if it is valid then he will merge your pull request to the repo**
[image]

that's all
Cheers :)

Comment: No. You get it opposite. I don't plan to do pull requests. I am plan to develop my own branch, but this branch must have possibility to get updates from master branch of main boilerplate. Because maybe they fix some bug or add some new functionality. And of course I want to be able to get it fast in my branch.