# Git proper method to keep multiple remotes in sync?

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

Here's the setup. I have a main github repository I'll call `team/repo`, and also a fork of it, which I'll call `me/repo`. On `me/repo` I made some changes in the `feature` branch (there is also a `master` branch), and create a pull request to the `develop` branch in `team/repo`. What is the proper method to get all the changes from the `develop` branch in `team/repo` (including the pull request I just made) back to the `master` branch on `me/repo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In reality, there is no "proper method", there are only different strategies/flows which different teams adopt.

## Gitflow branch management model?

It sounds like you might be following the [Gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) model of branch management.  Under Gitflow, you have a `master` branch, which is a semi-untouchable, set of commits that represent permanent copies of released code.  You also have an active `develop` branch (possibly more than one), `release` branches, and `feature` branches.

## Syncing a Fork

Since you have a fork of the repo, that's on Github as well (if I understand you right), and then you will also have a local repo on your PC.  Normally you would setup the fork (`me/repo`) as a the standard `origin` remote, and then setup the original `team/repo` as a remote called `upstream`.  When you want to update your fork, you pull down from the team repo (`upstream`) and then push those changes up to your fork (`origin`). If this part is any trouble, see [This Answer on "Syncing A Fork"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506355/6501141).

You may already have all this setup - it's not clear.  If it's not setup this way, the following may be off target.

## How do you get changes from A to B?

Now the heart of the answer - how to get your changes from `local/fork` ( to `team/repo` (or `upstream`, the original team central repo).

First, consider if the fork is necessary.  It likely is, but unless there are trust issues or this is a large distributed (likely multi-team) project, or open-source, the fork might not be needed. If you can, consider just working in a feature branch directly in `team/repo` and avoiding the added complexity of the fork.

Assuming the fork is needed, you a using a `feature` branch, and doing a pull request to `team/repo` on the `develop` branch.  This is fine, and will get your changes into the develop branch, either as a rebase in a series of commits, or as a combined single commit.

From here, it totally depends on your team's workflow as to how/when that change gets to `master`.  If the development follows Gitflow, there is no need for it to immediately going to `master`.  You should be branching your `feature` branch out of `develop`, not out of `master`.  And after your PR goes into `develop`, then just pull down the new `develop` commit into your local repo, and push up to your fork, and either create a new `feature` branch off `develop` or continue working in your existing `feature` branch until the next PR is needed.

Eventually, the team will merge `develop` commits into `master`, and possibly some of that will end up in `release` branches as well.  If so, there might be a time where you need to branch off `master` or a `release` branch instead of `develop`, but the new features should be branching off of `develop`, not `master` (`develop` would merge to and split back off of `master`).

Your team may handle this differently, but this should give you a feel for how it works and allow you to ask the right questions.  The main point is there is not necessarily a problem here, where your changes need to immediately get into `master`.  If they do put it into `master`, you will still pull them down from `upstream`, though you may need to checkout your local `master` and merge it to `upstream/master` to fast-forward it, then push that to your fork.