# Updating fork with upstream: git fetch-checkout-merge vs. git checkout-pull?

Tags: git, git-merge, pull-request, git-pull, git-fork

I am trying to understand how to keep my fork's master updated with the original repo's (from which I forked) master.

I read two documents:

- https://github.com/susam/gitpr#keep-your-fork-updated
- https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962#keeping-your-fork-up-to-date

Both documents provide more or less these steps:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Can these 3 steps be safely reduced to:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream/master
```

1. If yes, is there any scenario where the reduced two-step update
   would lead to problems but the three-step update would not?
2. Can these two steps be reduced to just one step?

Comment: You could consider [reducing it to zero steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085113/2303202)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it locally, and it seems to be working fine.

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
```

This will pull the `master` branch from repository specified by `upstream`, and merge it with the current branch you're on. If there are any conflicts you will be prompted to solve it manually.

I currently cannot think of any scenario where the two-step version will lead to any problem, provided that you're following the good practice of never committing to `master` branch of a forked repository. It's quite convenient and does the same thing as the three-step version.

For the last question, I'm afraid no (or conditionally). You need to switch to the `master` branch before merging `upstream/master` into your working tree, or it will lead to other problems. The condition is when you're always on branch `master` and never do any commits to it, you can omit the `checkout` step.

Answer (score 0):

As iBug pointed out, there's no single command to update your branch, but you could create an alias:

```
[alias]
    update = !git rev-parse --verify refs/heads/$1 && git checkout $1 -- && git pull origin $1
```

Now if you `git update master` it will switch you to the `master` branch, and pull `origin/master` into your branch.

Comment: Note: this is a quick & dirty alias, so there may be some edge cases that I haven't considered!