# update forked project on GitLab

Tags: gitlab, git-fork

I have forked project A in GitLab and create B and made some modification. After a month now i would like to update B project by pulling changes done in A.

How can i do this? I have option to create Merge request but i could't able  pull from A.

I know this could be very simple because if anyone like to contribute has eventually take pull before submitting merge request.

Please help. I found only this https://about.gitlab.com/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/

Basically i want to "Pull new updates from original GitLab repository into forked GitLab repository"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Comment: Thanks. That answer really helped me to find much easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an option to update my forked project via Android Studio. It may help some android developers.

I have added new Remote URL via Git -> Add Remote and named as upstream. Now i have done a fetch (Git -> Fetch) and found both Project A and Project B branches.

Now i can easily update my Project B using Merge request and pushed to origin.

Answer (score 0):

With [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#update-your-fork-from-the-gitlab-ui) (May 2023), you now can (only for Premium or Ultimate):

> ### Update your fork from the GitLab UI
>
> Managing your fork just got easier. When your fork is behind, select **Update fork** in the GitLab UI to catch it up with upstream changes. When your fork is ahead, select **Create merge request** to contribute your change back to the upstream project. Both operations previously required you to use the command line.
>
> See how many commits your fork is ahead (or behind) on your project’s main page and at **Repository > Files**. If merge conflicts exist, the UI gives guidance on how to resolve them using Git from the command line.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/fetch_new_upstream_contents_when_fork_is_behind.png -- Update your fork from the GitLab UI]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/forking_workflow.html#update-your-fork) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/330243).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Gitlab Premium (so mirroring is not possible) - you can use a `shell` function in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (`busybox` shell)

```
gitpull () {
        git checkout master
        git fetch upstream
        git pull upstream master
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                printf "\ngit fetched into master ok: pushing => fork (origin)\n\n"
                git push origin +master
        fi
}
```