# synching git repo with the original

Tags: github, git-branch, git-fork

I'm somewhat new to Git. I tried to google but couldn't find a clear answer. So here's the issue.

I have a forked repo from another repo

Original repo: https://github.com/org/original
Forked repo: https://github.com/user/original

And then let's say original repo master branch gets updated with new changes.

Now forked repo is not up to date.

How can I sync my forked repo with the original repo most recent state?

I would like to know this given that.

Scenario1: I have not done any changes to my forked repo.
Scenario2: I have done some changes to my forked repo.

Your feedback is highly appreciated. I'm sure a lot of new Git users will have the same question and I couldn't find a straightforward answer to this.

Comment: This might help: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#keep-your-fork-synced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)