# How to update a local git repository to the current state of the original github repo?

Tags: git, github

I am cloning a github repository 'A' to my local github account 'B'. Then I make a local copy of 'B' on my computer with `git clone`.

Then I might make a change, create a pull request etc.

After some time, the original repo 'A' advances, changes are being made to the repo 'A'. It is now different of my repo 'B'.

Is there a `git` command so that I can update 'B' to the current version of 'A', and the local copy on ly computer as well?

So far, I removed the checkout on the computer (`rm -rf`), I deleted the fork 'B', and started from scratch again. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add the original repo as a second remote.
To do this, just run

```
git remote add <local name> <url>
```

so for example

```
git remote add github https://github.com/myrepo
```

After you have done this, you can update your repository by pulling changes from the second remote.

```
git pull github
```

You can read more about this here
https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/#step-3-configure-git-to-sync-your-fork-with-the-original-spoon-knife-repository

Answer (score 0):

Add the original repo as remote.
Pull from that remote, or reset force if you need.

If you keep a local branch always pointing to the remote master, and don't touch it, you will be able to update that branch and then merge or rebase your local changes.