# Git: track remote repo + be able to change files in it

Tags: git, open-source, git-remote

I really need your help here.

I have a project that's based on an open-source solution hosted on Github. I need to be able to change files as required for my company, but at the same time sync the code with the original repo to keep it updated.

So I need something like

```
(get-latest-remote-repo-code --> apply-my-specific-adjustments --> production)
```

What's the most sensible way to achieve this? How would you handle this situation?

Comment: I would have multiple remotes. One called `origin`, a remote within my company where I push to regularly, and one called `upstream` where I fetch updates incase the open source repo updates.

Comment: @evolutionxbox will it work if I'm a number commits ahead after my modifications?

Comment: It should do... that's why we merge, or even `pull --rebase`.

Comment: Also keep your local branches separate from the upstream (using evolutionbox's naming) branches. Then merge from upstream/master to origin/ourMaster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)