# How to keep forked version of github project synced and what flow to use while committing changes?

Tags: git, github, git-gui

I was thinking of contributing to a slider project that I use in a lot of my projects. [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro).

I have a github account and have seen a few github tutorials, but I have a question, after I fork this project to my account and now suppose the owner makes a few changes to the main master. Will my forked version get the updated code, if not how do I keep my forked version updated ?

Also typically how do you contribute a path,

Fork `->` download to local using GIT GUI `->` make changes locally `->` commit + push to your master `->` send pull request to main master ? Is this the flow ?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you further -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository.

Comment: Alexander: "a lot" is two words, I've fixed this in a few of your posts now. Ditto the lower-case personal pronoun "I", which is always wrong when written in lower case. Would you be willing to use a spell-checker?

Comment: @halfer thanks noted