# Pull changes from original master to branch on fork

Tags: git

I forked project created branch made some changes on it and created pull request. Repo owner added some minor changes to master. I need to pull this changes from original project master to my fork branch.

I tried

```
git fetch origin
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+forked+repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try `git remote -v` you'll notice that `origin` points to your fork and not to the original repository.

In order to get changes from the original one, you should add a new remote:

```
git remote add upstream <URL>
```

and then pull changes from that remote:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Now if you show the remotes again, you should have something like:

```
$ git remote -v
origin    https://github.com/... (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/... (push)
upstream  https://github.com/... (fetch)
upstream  https://github.com/... (push)
```

Note that the name `upstream` is not special, you can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: Ok so I have `remotes/upstream/master` so next step to get changes from it into `myBranch` is to ...?

Comment: Well, now you have the updated branch, you can `git rebase upstream/master` (or a simple merge, or whatever you want).