# fetch from upstream faild for fork repo

Tags: git, github

I did a fork to GitHub repo and done some changes, now I need to rebase it against the 
master of the original repo

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
```

I tried with

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:kubernetes/ingress-nginx.git


 git fetch upstream
```

And I got an error

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository **'https://github.com/kubernetes/ingr/'** not found

I don’t understand why the suffix of the repo cut and how to overcome it, I just need to re-base against the master

I did this steps

[How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

I tried also with

```
 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:kubernetes/ingress-nginx.git
```

and

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx.git
```

and `git fetch upstream`

which doesnt helped

Answer (score 0):

i think the last two command should be workable ,if not try below check what's going wrong

```
mkdir /tmp/fetchtest && cd /tmp/fetchtest
git init
git remote add upstream https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx.git
git fetch
```