# github clone branch and merge process

Tags: github, clone

For a forked github repository, I have made additional changes on master branch. Now when the origin repository does versioned releases (say version 1.0.1, 1.0.2 and so on), how do I apply/merge my changes and release with the same version number? Is there any suggested or best practice that can be followed so that I can periodically merge my changes on top of the official release versions and release? Should I clone release version branches and manually merge?

I am sure there are others in a similar situation and any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are trying to sync up with original repository after forked their source and release with their schedule which includes your works. There is answer here for updating forked repository which I found could be useful to your case: 
[How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

> I can periodically merge my changes on top of the official release versions and release?

Yes

> Should I clone release version branches and manually merge?

There are solutions to do this automatically or manually, but it should have a feature branch which you will sync with original repository and merge your work on top of it before you want to release these change. Keep updating with the original with provided answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For better app, once you've made some changes, you should release a new version.

If you want to use the current version, just manually merge your changes into master branch and push to remote repo then push version tag same as current version.