# GitFlow Workflow, Pull from UpStream Master, then Merge into what?

Tags: git, git-flow

I am using git flow.

I have a repository inside of an organization that is the headquarters for a project, I also have a fork of this repository in my personal repos. When I make a change to the code, I create a pull request on the organization's repo.

My question is, how do I pull/merge that pull request's merge commit into my personal repo?

Do I `git checkout master && git pull upstream master`?

Then how do I manage the develop branch? `git checkout develop && git merge master` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

Comment: You didn't specifically mention it, but it sounds like you're using GitHub, so you should find the answer in the linked question.  (But yes, the basic process is to pull from `upstream`, then push to `origin`.)

Comment: My question is GitFlow specific, and it is not a fork, it a clone of another repository...

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be git-flow specific, since git-flow is just a branching model that defines what your branches mean; each branch can still be interacted with as normal too.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly is the relationship between the remote repo(s)?  You say in the question that you have a fork of the repo, but your comment says it's not a fork, so I'm a little confused.