# Merging a new version of a repository into my current one

Tags: git

My current repository (A) is based of an older version of repository B.

Now B has updated and I want to merge the changes of repository B onto my repository A.

Note the two repository has different URLs, repository A is my private repo and B is an open-source code base.

Comment: How about adding the address of B as a remote in your local clone of A, and pulling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)