# Github can't create a Fork from a branch, repository already exists

Tags: github

I am trying to create a FORK from a BRANCH. In the repo, I selected my branch to Fork.

[image: branch]

Then hit the FORK button but then GitHub won't let me FORK, it says the repo already exists...
I am part of 2 orgs and it won't let me FORK with the original org. I can only clone in a different org.
How do I fix that?

Note that "test-app" does not exist, any other name won't change anything.

[image: github error]

Comment: You are not forking a branch but a repository. So is there a good reason to not use the already forked repository to work on this branch? Maybe because the branch was not existing at the time you forked but it could be solved by learning how to sync with an upstream repository.

Comment: I am forking a Repo at a different branch. I do not want to set upstream repos. I can fork with a different org but that's not what I want. I want a fork and not upstream crap.

Comment: When you fork you have all the branches already there at the time you forked (you just have to checkout them). Forking a branch means nothing in Git! You fork a repo. You are not answering the question and don't get if it's by ignorance (of Git) or condescension (why use pejorative 'crap'!?!). Having an upstream remote and syncing it if needed IS the solution in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244456/717372

Comment: No, I wish to keep the network/compare between Forks. Upstream does not allow this, compared to 2 forks. Besides, you're the one very annoyed. I also don't care for 50 command lines when I should be able to do it with a simple fork. I've already answered my own question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will answer my own question.
Forking a repo with a different name within the same org is not available yet, but it will be added very soon it seems.

https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/330