# Having a fork auto update from original

Tags: git, github

I want to make a custom version of a girhub repo and remove some stuff. But I want to have the original's updates come into my fork, but my changes persist. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can this help?
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-or-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update or sync a forked repository on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-or-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github)