# How to sync forked repo with upstream via command line but without cloning locally?

Tags: git, github, repository

I know that a forked repo [can be quickly synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-or-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github) with the upstream repo [am I using the correct term?] directly on the GitHub web page, using the button "Sync fork".

I'd like to do essentially the same not via some browser, but from the command line, with some kind of `git ...` command. However, I'd like to avoid "cloning" or "downloading" the fork itself; in other words, I'd like *not* to have the files form the fork on my local machine. (The reason is that I have the upstream repo already cloned on my machine.)

Is this at all possible? How? Thank you!

Comment: "*I have the upstream repo already cloned*" So why not update your local clone and then push to fork? You can pull from one repo (upstream) and push to another (your fork).

Comment: @phd I didn't know I can do that! (complete noob about git). That should solve my problem. Please feel free to post your comment as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an upstream cloned locally so you don't need another clone. Just update your local clone from the upstream and push to the fork. To simplify things name your remote URLs `upstream` and `origin`. If your local clone already has `origin` rename it to `upstream` and add `origin` pointing to your fork. Something like this (note placeholders):

```bash
cd /path/to/local/clone
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/myuser/myfork.git
```

This need to be done only once. Now every time you need to update your fork from upstream do

```bash
cd /path/to/local/clone
git pull upstream master # or whatever branch you update
git push origin master
```

Comment: This has been very helpful also in directing me towards commands I didn't know existed. Thank you. If I may add a question: suppose nobody is really making changes to the forked repo, and my local copy of the original (upstream) repo is completely up to date. Could I then push to the fork with `git push https://github.com/otheruser/fork.git master`, without renaming?

Comment: Edit: looks like it works!

Comment: @pglpm `git push https://github.com/otheruser/fork.git master` works for sure but you will not have remote-tracking branch `origin/master` that should point to the last commit pushed to the fork. It's not required but I find it quite convenient. Also I find convenient to type `git push origin master` — it's simpler, shorter and bash completion works.

Comment: Both good points, thank you!