# Don't understand forking

Tags: git, bitbucket

We just set up a project with bitbucket. We put our 'production'[P] code on a repo, and then i created a fork[m] of it, and then my co-worker[C] also created a fork of it.

```
    [P]
   /   \
 [M]   [C]
```

I made some changes, and created a pull request and accepted it, so [P] now has my code, [M].

Here is where I am confused. How does [C], my coworkers repo get the updated code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your coworker needs to pull from P.

If you're working on the `master` branch in P, then the command would be...

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: if we are actually talking about **[forking](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+bitbucket+Repository#ForkingabitbucketRepository-Step-by-StepExample%E2%80%93NowthePullRequest)** (which is the act of cloning a repo on the *server* side) and not simple cloning, then the schema is:

```
             BitBucket

    ------------[P]-----------
    |            ^           |
    |            |           |
 (forked) (pull request)  (forked)
    |                        |
    v                        v
   [M]                      [C]
    |                        |
----|------------------------|-----  
    |   Local workstations   |
    |                        |
 (git clone)             (git clone)
    |                        |
    v                        v
 [MLocal]                  [CLocal]
```

In other words, `M` and `C` are on the BitBucket servers, not on `Muser` and `Cuser` local workstations.
'`origin`' would be their respective [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) repo of `MLocal` and `CLocal`, that is M or C, **not `P`**.
(See "[What is the difference between origin and upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)", for GitHub, but applies also for BitBucket)

This is useful for Muser because:

- `Muser` might not want to push directly to `P` (he could though, he is the owner of `P` on BitBucket), so here, repo `M` acts as his "buffer"
- `Cuser` has no right to push on `P`, so he must to fork as well

In that case, for `Cuser` to see any updates on `P`, he needs to add `P` as a remote to `CLocal` repo (ie his cloned local repo of his fork)

```
git remote add P https://bitbucket.org/Puser/P
git pull P master
```

Once those new changes are integrated and tested locally (on `CLocal`), they can be pushed back to `C`, along with new evolutions introduced by `Cuser`. Only those new modifications will be part of a [pull request](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+bitbucket+Repository#ForkingabitbucketRepository-Step-by-StepExample%E2%80%93NowthePullRequest), for `Muser` (and `P` owner) to examine and add to P.

Similarly, `Muser` would need to add `P` as a remote to `MLocal`, in order to get back any modifications from `C` that were accepted into `P`.