# How do I change the remote source of my github repo?

Tags: github, fork

I forked a repo and set everything up on my local machine. However, when I do 'git remote -v' it shows the original repo as my fetch and push source. I want it to by from my forked repo. How do I change it over to that without starting all over? And then, how do I add an upstream to the original repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [git remote man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

```
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/forkname
 git remote add upstream https://github.com/maintainer/reponame
```

See also the examples of [GitHub: Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url).

```
set-url
```

> Changes URL remote points to.

You will then be able to fetch from upstream, and push to origin:
See "[What is the difference between `origin` and `upstream` in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)".