# How to tell git to ignore git sub modules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My "real" `.git` folder is in `/var/www`. I want to push the whole folder to github. Unfortunately, a few git sub modules are excluded.

For example the folder `w/extensions/Lingo` is excluded. But `w/extensions/Lingo/.git` isn't "my" git sub module. Git was only used to download `w/extensions/Lingo` and will be used to update that folder. No own development planed.

How can I tell my "real" git `/var/www/.git` to ignore any sub modules such as `w/extensions/Lingo/.git`?

In other words, what I want to tell git is "just treat any file in `/var/www/*` as normal file".

Answer (score 2):

`www/extensions/Lingo` should not  be ignored: what you will push is the [gitlink (special entry, mode 16000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) which represents (in the working tree of the main repo) the SHA1 currently checked out in `www/extensions/Lingo`.

You can check that by doing a [`git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23151138/6309) (without trailing slash):

```
cd /var/www
git log -- extensions/Lingo
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore it, but to treat it as normal folder. How to do that?

Comment: @adrelanos it is a submodule: it isn't meant to be treated as a normal folder, but as a marker to the content of another repo: once you clone what you pushed to GitHub, a simple `git submodule update --init` will restore the content of that folder.

Comment: I pushed it to github. When someone clones it, they end up with an empty `/www/w/extensions/Lingo`. Not what I want.

Comment: @adrelanos yes, it is what you can expect from a submodule: it isn't an empty folder, but a special icon: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585206/6309 It is the marker (the gitlink) I mention in my answer.

Comment: This is over complicating things. Hence I want to treat them as normal folders. I am using many such submodules (not on purpose, they just happen to be). Now when I run `git submodule update --init`, I get `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'w/extensions/BreadCrumbs2'`.

Comment: @adrelanos no, it doesn't add complexity; it does what a submodule is supposed to do: a simple light-weight marker to remember a repo content. And your error message has nothing to do with `Lingo`, but with another submodule which, apparently, isn't declared in your .gitmodules.

Comment: @adrelanos remember, this isn't just about treating a submodule "like a regular folder": it is about storing the *exact version* if that folder content.

Comment: @adrelanos for your error message, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4162672/6309. `git rm` + `git submodule add`.

Comment: Git submodules open up to a whole new learning curve and chain of new issues. Next one after creating the .gitmodules file with ~15 sub modules, I end up getting `fatal: reference is not a tree: 19e577ac3b16eba79a0d4519d18a1306e95d4e49`. It is probably because of a minor change (optimized image with optipng script), that can not be found in upstream's repository. The simple task "just get /var/www folder published on github" extends to multiple hours of work. Ironically, svn could get this specific job done easier, because it ignores .git folders. That's what I meant with added complexity.

Comment: @adrelanos not multiple hours of work: if you modify anything in a submodule, you must push it (before going back to the parent repo, add, commit and push). I didn't mention it because you said in your question "No own development planed.". But I explain more on submodules at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979194/6309

Comment: "No own development planed", I forgot, that a simple image optimization script was run over that folder. I don't consider this development. So for this change in the submodule, to push it somewhere, I would have to create a separate remote repository for the submodule?

Comment: @adrelanos yes, if you don't have write access to the original repo of that submodule, you would have to fork it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309), change the remote origin, and push to your fork (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13025673/6309).

Comment: I understand. This seems overkill for the real task ("just get /var/www folder published on github") at hand. Maybe a workaround could be to no let the parent `/var/www/.git` see `w/extensions/Lingo/.git` etc. by using file permissions can be used.

Comment: @adrelanos no it isn't overkill: it is called component approach (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7322295/6309), in which you register in your main repo the exact configuration you need for said parent repo to work, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2897157/6309.

Answer (score 2):

If you *insist* including the content of a submodule in your repo, you can do a:

```
git submodule deinit Lingo 
git rm -r --cached extensions/Lingo
rm -R extensions/Lingo/.git # (if it is still there)
git add extensions/Lingo
```

(As I detail in "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)")

The `--cached` make sure you don't remove the content of that folder in your working tree.

Comment: This would probably work, but then the ability to update extension/Lingo using a simple `git fetch` + `git merge origin/master` is lost.

Comment: @adrelanos of course, that is why it is a submodule! The last alternative is to make it a subtree: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/ (beware of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14448784/6309 though)

Comment: @adrelanos other alternative: http://jayunit100.blogspot.fr/2013/12/git-submodules-are-to-hot-subtrees-are.html But I would simply keep submodules ;)

Comment: I feel like there are valid reasons to kill the submodule triggers in git. I just added a new ember.js project in a folder inside of a larger client project. Since running 'ember new my-ember-project' created a .git folder inside of the 'my-ember-project' folder, the primary repo for the project wanted to pick it up as a submodule. It wasn't actually a submodule, but was generated by the ember cli as a convenience. In order to have the parent repo actually track this as a set of files, the above commands (mainly the rm -R my-ember-project/.git part) was very helpful in fixing the problem.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose well done: that would indeed make the content of that repo visible, instead of being part of a nested repo.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend doing this, but it sounds like you're dead-set... Note that this will cause files from your "submodule" to be committed in *two places*, and keeping them in sync will be an additional challenge.

**My opinion is that this is at least as complicated as submodules, and since it's a weird thing to do other developers who want to contribute will likely be confused.**

You *could* move the `.git` directory out of your submodule directory so that

1. your main Git repository does not view the "submodule" directory as a submodule, and
2. you can still fetch from upstream.

Here is a short example:

1. Clone something (your "inner repository") into a subdirectory of your main repository:

   ```
   ~ $ cd repo
   ~/repo/ $ git clone git://some-other-repo.git/
   ```
2. Create a directory to hold the `.git` directory from your inner repository somewhere outside of your main repository, and move your inner `.git` directory there:

   ```
   ~/repo/ $ cd ..
   ~ $ mkdir -p fake-submodules/some-other-repo/
   ~ $ mv ~/repo/some-other-repo/.git fake-submodules/some-other-repo/
   ```
3. Now, from your main repository you can add all of the files and commit as usual:

   ```
   ~ $ cd repo
   ~/repo/ $ git add some-other-repo
   ~/repo/ $ git commit -m "Add some other repo"
   ```
4. And you can fetch updates from your upstream repository using Git's `--work-tree` option:

   ```
   ~/repo/ $ cd ../fake-submodules/some-other-repo
   ~/fake-submodules/some-other-repo/ $ git --work-tree ../../repo/some-other-repo status
   ~/fake-submodules/some-other-repo/ $ git --work-tree ../../repo/some-other-repo fetch
   ~/fake-submodules/some-other-repo/ $ git --work-tree ../../repo/some-other-repo merge origin/master
   ```

Note that you would have to perform all Git operations for your inner repository from its `fake-submodules` directory. You will probably want to do something like `git config core.worktree ../../repo/some-other-repo` to avoid having to type the `--work-tree` option in each time.

**Again, please reconsider doing this.** Git's submodules may not be perfect, but at least they're widely used and understood. As VonC says, there are other more appropriate options as well, like subtrees.