# update fork on GitHub for Windows?

Tags: github

I am currently using the Windows Github GUI and its pretty cool looking and easy so I'm trying to use it as often.  A problem I encountered is when I fork a project I don't know how to update that fork with the git

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GitHub for Windows only supports one remote for now (`origin`, which reference your fork).

So you need to manually add a remote (called '`upstream`') referencing the original repo, in order for you to be able to pull (from the CLI) from `upstream`, updating your local repo and allowing you to push (this time with the GUI) the new commits to your fork.

See "[What is the difference between origin and upstream in github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)" for more.

Answer (score 30):

And just for reference I copy here the detailed instructions from a post at http://processwire.com/talk/topic/1565-github-for-windows/:

- In "GitHub for Windows" local repositories view, right-click and choose "`open a shell here`"
- This will open a shell already in the right directory. Type the following commands:

```
# Assigns the original repo to a remote called "upstream"
git remote add upstream https://github.com/path_to_your_repository.git 

# Pulls in changes from the original repo not present in your local repository, 
# without modifying your files. 
# Allows you to review first.
git fetch upstream 

# merge fetched changes into your working files.
git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: Nice concrete addition to my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for fixing the formatting for me. I learned from it. Also, I had at first tried to add a comment to your answer instead of posting a new answer but the allowed length of comments was not sufficient.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2013/06/git-remote-add-upstream-fatal-remote-upstream-already-exists.html if you are getting "fatal 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository" error

Answer (score 2):

> **Syncing a fork**
>
> Sync a fork of a repository to keep it up-to-date with the upstream
>   repository.
>
> Tip: Before you can sync your fork with an upstream repository, you
>   must [configure a remote that points to the upstream repository](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork) in Git.
>
> **1.** Open Terminal (for Mac users) or the command prompt (for Windows and Linux users).
>
> **2.** Change the current working directory to your local project.
>
> **3.** Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to `master` will be stored in a local
>   branch, `upstream/master`.
>
> ```
> $ git fetch upstream
> ```
>
> **4.** Check out your fork's local `master` branch.
>
> ```
> $ git checkout master
> ```
>
> **5.** Merge the changes from `upstream/master` into your local `master` branch. This brings your fork's `master` branch into sync
>   with the upstream repository, without losing your local changes.
>
> ```
> $ git merge upstream/master
> ```
>
> ---
>
> If your **local branch didn't have any unique commits**, Git will instead
>   perform a "fast-forward":
>
> ```
> $ git merge upstream/master
> ```
>
> Tip: Syncing your fork only updates your local copy of the repository.
>   To update your fork on GitHub, you must push your changes.

*Source:* https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

[image]

In Github for Windows (GUI application), press button `Sync`, then application will upload changed files to your own repository (at Github.com).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to sync a fork repository from an original repository?

For easy understand, I call an reality example: Sync this repository: https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy from https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy

There’re all steps:

```
Last login: Fri Sep  2 08:45:34 on ttys000
Dos-MacBook-Pro:~ donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:~ donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:~ donhuvy$ ls
AndroidStudioProjects   IdeaProjects        Public
Applications        Library         PycharmProjects
Desktop         Movies          example.dump
Documents       Music           pgadmin.log
Downloads       Pictures        sun-appserv-samples
Dos-MacBook-Pro:~ donhuvy$ cd Documents/
Dos-MacBook-Pro:Documents donhuvy$ ls
$RECYCLE.BIN
13256069_130212657393823_216708148326317354_n.jpg
1511456_1453604554870601_599093550_n.jpg
4578-rc007-jquery_online.pdf
Apps
Programming ebooks
Setup
Treasure_Island_NT.pdf
Video tutorial
Virtual Machines.localized
films
postgresql-9.0-A4.pdf
program_files
source_code
vy.sql
workspace_javaee
Dos-MacBook-Pro:Documents donhuvy$ cd source_code/
Dos-MacBook-Pro:source_code donhuvy$ ls
github.com
Dos-MacBook-Pro:source_code donhuvy$ cd github.com/
Dos-MacBook-Pro:github.com donhuvy$ ls
AurelioDeRosa   donhuvy     hibernate-orm   scrapy      spring-projects
Dos-MacBook-Pro:github.com donhuvy$ cd donhuvy/
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ ls
ZohoCRM_integration jquery3_examples
java_examples       real_estate
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ git clone https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git
Cloning into 'scrapy'...
remote: Counting objects: 40481, done.
remote: Total 40481 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 40481
Receiving objects: 100% (40481/40481), 13.98 MiB | 746.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (21135/21135), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ '
> 
> 
> 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ ls
ZohoCRM_integration jquery3_examples    scrapy
java_examples       real_estate
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ cd sc
-bash: cd: sc: No such file or directory
Dos-MacBook-Pro:donhuvy donhuvy$ cd scrapy/
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ ls
AUTHORS         README.rst      requirements.txt
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  artwork         scrapy
CONTRIBUTING.md     conftest.py     sep
INSTALL         debian          setup.cfg
LICENSE         docs            setup.py
MANIFEST.in     extras          tests
Makefile.buildbot   pytest.ini      tox.ini
NEWS            requirements-py3.txt
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git log
commit ab42e2b5d531cbbf2ee46b49726604c90becbd3d
Author: vydn <v@vyhn.net>
Date:   Sat Apr 2 06:08:28 2016 +0700

    Change the content

    Change the content

commit bf7f67549378269c3976afc89abcf9c2190d242f
Merge: 9d8c368 9250a5b
Author: Paul Tremberth <paul.tremberth@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 1 15:47:06 2016 +0200

    Merge pull request #1847 from aron-bordin/add_blocking_storage_path_setting

    [MRG+2] added BLOCKING_FEED_STORAGE_PATH to settings

commit 9250a5bffa91c24dbea5c5d64c3c7cd9992a6ee7
Author: Aron Bordin <aron.bordin@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Mar 5 19:36:02 2016 -0300

    added FEED_TEMPDIR to settings

commit 9d8c368ce8a24d7adb63b731df1359f3b05f3bdd
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ 
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git fetch upstream
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (push)
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git (push)
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git fetch upstream
remote: Counting objects: 1329, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 1329 (delta 600), reused 599 (delta 599), pack-reused 723
Receiving objects: 100% (1329/1329), 425.28 KiB | 325.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (920/920), completed with 141 local objects.
From https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy
 * [new branch]      0.12       -> upstream/0.12
 * [new branch]      0.14       -> upstream/0.14
 * [new branch]      0.16       -> upstream/0.16
 * [new branch]      0.18       -> upstream/0.18
 * [new branch]      0.20       -> upstream/0.20
 * [new branch]      0.22       -> upstream/0.22
 * [new branch]      0.24       -> upstream/0.24
 * [new branch]      1.0        -> upstream/1.0
 * [new branch]      1.1        -> upstream/1.1
 * [new branch]      asyncio    -> upstream/asyncio
 * [new branch]      deprecate-make-requests-from-url -> upstream/deprecate-make-requests-from-url
 * [new branch]      disable-toplevel-2 -> upstream/disable-toplevel-2
 * [new branch]      doc-arch-overview2 -> upstream/doc-arch-overview2
 * [new branch]      feature-1371-download-prios -> upstream/feature-1371-download-prios
 * [new branch]      fix-1330   -> upstream/fix-1330
 * [new branch]      fix-util-function-to-work-outside-project-dir -> upstream/fix-util-function-to-work-outside-project-dir
 * [new branch]      link-encoding -> upstream/link-encoding
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
 * [new branch]      no-max-rss -> upstream/no-max-rss
 * [new branch]      py3-chunked -> upstream/py3-chunked
 * [new branch]      release-notes-1.1.2-master -> upstream/release-notes-1.1.2-master
 * [new branch]      remove-prerelease-configuration -> upstream/remove-prerelease-configuration
 * [new tag]         1.0.6      -> 1.0.6
 * [new tag]         1.1.2      -> 1.1.2
 * [new tag]         1.1.0      -> 1.1.0
 * [new tag]         1.1.0rc4   -> 1.1.0rc4
 * [new tag]         1.1.1      -> 1.1.1
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git merge upstream/master
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git commit -m "update"
[master 6f16b46] update
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git push
Counting objects: 915, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (380/380), done.
Writing objects: 100% (915/915), 235.84 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 915 (delta 677), reused 769 (delta 535)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (677/677), completed with 99 local objects.
To https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git
   ab42e2b..6f16b46  master -> master
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Dos-MacBook-Pro:scrapy donhuvy$
```

[image]

Important points:

**Step 1.** Change directory:

```
cd /Users/donhuvy/Documents/source_code/github.com/donhuvy/
```

To be sure:

```
pwd
```

**Step 2.** Go to https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy look at the top right, copy repository link

```
https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git
```

**Step 3.** Clone from server to local

```
git clone https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git
```

**Step 4.** Go to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy , look at the top right, copy repository link

```
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git
```

**Step 5.** Add upstream repository link

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git
```

**Step 6.** Check repo list:
    git remote -v

Result:

origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/donhuvy/scrapy.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git (push)

**Step 7.** Fetch upstream

```
git fetch upstream
```

**Step 8.** Get master branch from upstream repo

```
git checkout master
```

**Step 9.** Merge source code:

```
git merge upstream/master
```

Vim editor open inside terminal, then you edit commit message, press **i** for starting edit, press **esc**, **:wq!** for quit and save.

**Step 10.** Make a commit

```
git commit -m "update"
```

**Step 11.** Push
**git push**

**Step 12.** To be sure

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Of course, I try to my post have no 13rd step.
```

Reference:

https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/
https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/