# How to use github with local system and server?

Tags: git, github

I am still trying to find the best way to use github with my local system and server. I am assuming it is -

Code on your local system, push it on github and from there, download it on your live server

without sounding too subjective, Is this the standard way to use git with local system and server ?

Edit - I found this [What is the difference between origin and upstream on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github) which has really good pic of clone/fork and local repo, so ideally it looks to be your_server <--> github <--> local_server/repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard" way of working with git. You can do either way, pull from a repo on your machine or a build or test server from the server. Or, pull from github. It may very well depend on your topology and if firewalls are going to get in the way.