# use git submodule with read-only access

Tags: git, git-submodules

How to push changes in a git submodule where i have only read-only access.

My problem is when I try to do `git submodule update`. I get a `fatal: reference is not a tree` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that submodule is on GitHub, you would need to:

- [fork it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901), and use that repo as your submodule

  - make you modification in that submodule and push
  - commit the parent repo
- modify the submodule url (by [editing the .gitmodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309) in the parent repo)

Then your `git submodule update` will work.