# How to setup EGit in an Eclipse Joomla development project to work on a third party module hosted on GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, joomla, github, egit, eclipse-pdt

I am new to Git/GitHub. I do have an Eclipse Indigo Joomla 2.5 workspace on an freshly installed Joomla instance. I can launch an http request, set a breakpoint somewhere in the Joomla code and start stepping into the code in a debug session. So, working environment !

I would like to contribute to a third party Joomla module hosted on GitHub. How can I clone the code of the module from the GitHub repo and start making improvements to it. I also plan to work on other third party modules or plugins later, from the same workspace if this is possible.

My concern is: how do I setup EGit so that I can have several independant local Git repo in the same workspace and add, branch, merge, push on them independantly ? Thanks for your answer !

Jean-Pierre

Comment: I did configure EGit using the info belpw, i.e. with an upstream remote in addition to my fork on GitHub. I did add a submodule. But I can't do any add to the index or commit. Finally I gave up using EGit and did switch to TortoiseGit which nicely and intuitively covers all the Git features !

Answer (score 2):

> How can I clone the code of the module from the GitHub repo and start making improvements to it

You need to [fork it first](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo), and then [make some pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309).

You can add each of those repos in your Eclipse workspace (see [adding a repository manually](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Repository_manually)).
However, you would need to manage branches and pushing for each and every repos.

I would also advise to add for each repo the remote address of the [original upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309):

[image: upstream repo]

That way, you can easily rebase your work on top of the latest of the original repo you have forked.