# Github pull request

Tags: github

I am still new to github and now I am confused. I forked a repo a while ago. Then locally on my computer pulled the changes from the original repo and merged them into mine. Then I did my change and committed it. Then I pushed everything to my forked repo.

Now I want to send a pull request. But I just want to send my one commit and not everything else (which is already in the original repo). But I can't find a way to do so.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Sarah . Please go through this link . This will give you good understanding of git http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a GitHub pull request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to to your forked repo, and then click on `Compare and Review`

- Select the target branch to merge
- `Click to create a pull request for this comparison`
- Enter a title and description for your pull request
- Click `Send pull request`

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request