# How to send pull request for new file when already a pull request exists

Tags: git, github

I have this situation. I forked a repo from github. I made some changes in a separate branch locally. Then merged it with master. Then i pushed it to my github repo. I also send the pull request.

Somebody made changes in a file on the main repo. I want to fetch it and make changes in that file. I want to send its pull request separately.

How do i start from my local repo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I made some changes in a separate branch locally. Then merged it with master

Don't: you should make a pull request from the branch which isn't present in the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** you have forked.
That way, you can keep `master` always in sync with the `master` of the upstream (original) repo.

See "[a couple of tips on pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)" for more.

[image: upstream and fork]

That means:

> I forked a repo from github. I made some changes in a separate branch locally

Push that branch, and make your pull request from that branch (with a target: `upstream repo/master`)

You can then pull from upstream to update your master (which you never touch: you just add commits from the upstream repo to your local clone, and push master to your fork to keep it up-to-date).

Then you can rebase your local branch on top of the updated master, check that everything is still working, and **push --force** to your fork that branch.

The magic is: your existing pull request will automatically be updated with your new commits from that branch you just forced push.

---

In details:

```
cd /local/path/to/your/clone
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/original_repo
git fetch upstream

git checkout master
# reset master to upstream master
git reset --hard upstream/master

git checkout yourBranch
git rebase master
# check that everything works

git push -f origin master
git push -f origin yourBranch
# Make your pull request from your branch in your fork on GitHub
```

---

Once that is done, future evolutions to your patch mean:

```
# update master with upstream master new commits
git checkout master
git pull upstream master

# rebase your local branch
git checkout YourBranch
git rebase master
# check that everything still works

git push origin master
git push origin yourBranch
# your pull request will AUTOMATICALLY BE UPDATED!
# nothing to do on GitHub
```

Comment: it would be great if you can add specifi commands because in past i have burned myself with using commands from here and there.

Comment: I have pushed that old_pull_req branch and made pull request from it. How do i force my Master to be like main repo ?

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI if you never committed (or merge to) on your `master`, yes. That is why I suggest a `git reset --hard upstream/master`, to be sure your master is clean. Once that is done, subsequent `git pull upstream master` will work as expected.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI I have added a second set of commands, once your local repo is correctly in sync with upstream.