# What does "This branch is 0 commits ahead and 0 commits behind master" mean on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

GitHub screenshot:

[image]

There's only one branch, master. `git status` says there's nothing to commit. How is that branch zero commits ahead and behind itself?

I see this on GitHub forks. Is it just a confusing status message?

Comment: I'd guess that this is just a bug. Your master seems to be actually 5 commits ahead of the master of the repository you forked from. (looking at the compare link). And a branch (being only a pointer to a particular commit) will always be 0 commits ahead and behind itself (as it's pointing to the same commit as itself). Usually ahead/behind are for comparing corresponding branches in different repositories (e.g. origin vs. local), or possibly different branches in the same repository.

Comment: @Charlie, that's the answer and worth upvotes if you post it as such ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is **not** a bug.

Once you fork a repo, each of your branch is compared to the branch which is common between the fork and the original repo.
That gives you a clear indication about you can or not make a pull request.

In this instance, your branch is `master`, which is means it is compared with itself, since `master` is also in the [original repo](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-crypto-base).
Hence the "`0 commit ahead and 0 commit behind`" (with itself) message.

If you had done a commit of your own on, as I mention in "[couple of tips on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)", on a **dedicated branch** made from `master`, then your branch would have been a commit ahead of `master`.
You could then have made a pull request, from the owner of the first repo to consider.

[image: fork]

In any case, the purpose of that message is to **remind you that the main goal of a fork is to collaborate and contribute back**:

- if your dedicated branch is behind, you want to rebase it against `origin/branch` (which you are supposed to keep in sync with the original repo, in other words, you are not supposed to work directly on `master`) in order to make sure your own work is compatible with the latest commits of the first repo,
- if your branch is ahead, you could consider making a pull request and giving back.

Comment: I think you're correct about how the mechanics should work, however in this particular case though, wouldn't: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-crypto-base/ be the original repo (the one that is forked from)? Since that repo does not contain afbba9f, the difference between the original:master and fork:master would not be 0/0 as the message indicates? (and still indicates despite now being further ahead of the original master?)

Comment: @Charlie Thank you for the comment. Turns out, I wasn't quite correct about the *exact* mechanics. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: @VonC - 348k?! *gasp*

Comment: @DanDascalescu this (348k) is just a meaningless number. What matters is if my answer helped you understand that "ahead/behind" message: it helps reinforce the notion that you should always work on dedicated branch in a fork (at least one where you intend to contribute back). "Dedicated branch" means "a branch which doesn't exist in the original repo".