# Push to a github project

Tags: git, github

I'm using a github project from another person, and I made a patch I think it could be usefull.

I've try a basic git push but I have this error

```
remote: Permission to *****.git denied to *****.

fatal: unable to access `'https://github.com/***/***/'`: The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How it's the correct way to push the change for the author considers it?

Thanks!

Comment: fork, clone, update own branch, issue push, pull request.

Comment: Make a fork, or ask/call him... What will you think if someone want to repaint your home in pink becuase he think it's better ?

Comment: @Jahnux73 He will need to copy the house first. :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Hope he lives in a hut :)

Comment: I'm just new with this stuff. I thought a push will send it a request approval. It's meaby a noob question, but I'm actualy a noob with that. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a GitHub pull request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the author gave you commit access, you should [create a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request). Here's more information about [using pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

Basically, you fork the repository into your account. You make the changes and you ask the author to compare your changes in your account with the ones in the main repository.

Github makes all easy by using their pull request feature.

Comment: Ok, all the stuff I need are here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Push to your github and create a pull request.

How to work with github in one image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a permission issue, you need to ask permission from the guy you pulled this code from in order to push it back to the repository.

more than that, I suggest you read a git manual before starting working with it, because a simple "Push" have to come after a commit, and after a check that nothing is changed in the remote repository (do an extra pull before pushing again is advised).