# Possible pull request workflow to merge a branch into master

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm new to GitHub pull requests and wondering if this would work.

Right now I branch off master, make changes and commit periodically, then at some point I'll checkout master again and run `git pull` to get the latest from origin.

Next, I checkout my branch and call `git rebase -i master` to apply those changes and to make sure I don't have any conflicts when the time comes to merge back to master.

I'll go through that cycle periodically while working.  When I'm ready to integrate to the master branch I checkout master and call `git merge <my branch>` then push to the repository.

But with pull requests do I need to take that last step?  Instead, can I submit a pull request on my branch and then on GitHub apply it to master?

(I'm also open to improvements on my existing workflow, if any are apparent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with pull requests do I need to take that last step? Instead, can I submit a pull request on my branch and then on GitHub apply it to master?

1. you should always submit a pull request from a branch that you have push to your GitHub fork.
2. You even can rebase that branch on top of master, git push --force that branch to your fork, **and your existing pull request will be updated. Automatically**

The only merge of your branch to master will take place in the original repo by the main maintainer, should he/she chose to accept your pull request.

See more with [couple of tips for pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309).

Comment: Thanks for the tips...ah, in the instances where I haven't forked, just branched, can I still do a pull request from the branch?

Comment: @larryq pull request, as in "GitHub pull request", is only done from a fork at the GitGub server. "Just branch" means you have cloned a repo of yours (to which you can push back to) and you will have to merge your branch locally, pushing the resulting merge commit. But that is different from a "pull request".

Comment: I thought that as well, but when I push my local branch to GitHub (via git push --set-upstream origin <my branch>) I can create a pull request on GitHub for it.  I thought that was unusual, can you think of why that would work?  I looked in GitHub under my account and I have two forks, neither for this particular repo.

Comment: @larryq see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/178489: it can help for monitoring how a branch progress before merging it back to master. You benefit from all the features around PR (Pull Request) for that branch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can submit a pull request on your branch and merge it to master in GitHub.

It will be best to do this when working with a Pull Request on a public repo where your changes will be reviewed before being merged back into the master of the repo.