# github pull request from master branch, can I keep working on other branches before it is merged?

Tags: github

I found a quick bug to fix in a project.  I never made a development branch and when I finished with this bug fix I did a pull request for the new changes on the master branch.

While I'm waiting for that request to be merged I found another unrelated bug to work on.  Can I make a new branch for bug #2 and work on that separately or will any changes be included in the still pending pull request from the first fix?

Is there anyway to fix this other than just waiting for it to be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While I'm waiting for that request to be merged I found another unrelated bug to work on. Can I make a new branch for bug #2 and work on that separately or will any changes be included in the still pending pull request from the first fix?

Yes, you can make a new branch: any changes on it will remain for that branch only.

If you add and push new commits on the initial branch you made a PR from, then that PR would be automatically updated, as I explain in "[couple of tips for pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

But any changes to a *new* branch wouldn't impact the PR in any way.